# android : roundedImageView with VectorDrawables

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, bitmapdrawable

I am getting error while setting Vector Drawables to RoundedImageView. I am clear with error I am getting, its because I am trying to cast a drawable to BitmapDrawable but it should be VectorDrawable (If I am not wrong), So can anyone suggest me the way to handle any type of images whether it is jpg, png or vector.

**RoundedImageView.java:**

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap(); // line no 43
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

**My Error Log:**

```
01-05 16:12:55.474 29943-29943/com.knowaguy.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.knowaguy.app, PID: 29943
                                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
at com.knowaguy.app.customViews.RoundedImageView.onDraw(RoundedImageView.java:43)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:3588)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3097)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Chore
```

Comment: in `getCroppedBitmap` use a `Drawable` as a parameter, not `Bitmap`

Comment: @pskink Yes sir.. I am getting some hint.. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: just use: `public static void croppDrawable(Canvas c, Drawable d, int radius)` to crop your input `Drawable` that way you can use any `Drawable` you want, for example: `BitmapDrawable` `VectorDrawable` etc

Answer (score 1):

There may be an alternate approach too but I am not sure it will be efficient, You can convert your `VectorDrawable` to `Bitmap` since the method getBitmapDrawable() on a non instance of `BitmapDrwable` will throw exception( as you see in your case).

Use the following method to obtain a bitmap from drawable -

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int drawableId) {
    Drawable vectorDrawable;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        vectorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId,null);
    }else {
        vectorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    }
    int h = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int w = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

    //Setting a default height in pixel if intrinsinc height or width is not found , eg in case of a shape drawable
    h=h>0?h:96;
    w=w>0?w:96;

    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: What I like about your method is that it does not rely on Lollipop and above API  exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer, which I found elsewhere on stackoverflow, in order to show Sanjeet an alternate solution that I mentioned. Because the min API is so high this way, I don't claim that it is the best solution.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private Bitmap _getBitmap(Context c, int svg_id) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, svg_id);
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return _getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap _getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```